# Callback function for mouse click on object with Cocoa Drawing?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, graphics, core-graphics

I have a two part question.

I wan't do do some basic shape drawing (and make it interactive) in Objective-C. It looks like there is a fem different Apple libraries for doing this. Cocoa Drawing, Core Graphics, QuartzGL and you can also write OpenGL directly.

**Q1:** What is the difference between these libraries/technologies?

**Q2:** Does any one of these offer a callback function for when a graphical object (e.g. a circle) is clicked (like in one of the graphical libraries for Java)? Or something similar? Or do I have to do it manually as with OpenGL — calculating boundaries and check pixel location of mouse click?

Thanks. :)

Comment: Asking for comparisons of different frameworks is far too broad for Stackoverflow. Do some reading!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The open source [DrawKit framework](http://drawkit.github.io) will probably provide all you need.

DrawKit is based on a combination of CoreGraphics and Cocoa Drawing. The framework provides an Objective-C interface and provides a platform on which you can quickly build your own interface and behaviours.

Built-into DrawKit is the ability to work with text, vector objects, and bitmaps:

[image: DrawKit sample image]

Comment: Looks great, thank you! But does it have some sort of callback function for when an object is selected? I have a tree structure of shapes, that I need to associate with the different graphical objects, so when sombody e.g. clicks the circle, a function in the correct object in my tree.

Comment: You can inherit from a DrawKit object and respond to interaction, or you can inherit from the drawing layer and customise selection/clicking behaviour there; http://drawkit.github.io/api/interface_d_k_object_drawing_layer.html It is a very capable framework – maybe much more than you immediately need.

Comment: DrawKit looks kind of abandoned, though - the latest beta from the web site is targeting 10.4 and doesn't even build..?

Comment: Oh, sorry: it's just the zips on the web page that are out of date, the GitHub version seems pretty current :-)